# Testacular: run tests with Chrome extensions disabled

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, karma-runner

When running a smoke test in Google Chrome with Testacular configured with `singleRun: true` I found that some extensions like LastPass would open a first run window with a yes/no prompt every time. You would have to click the LastPass prompt for the test suite to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this with a custom browser script.

1. In your Testacular conf, change `browsers = ['Chrome']` to `[__dirname + '/chrome_without_extensions.sh']` (I think the path needs to be absolute)
2. Create a new file called **chrome_without_extensions.sh** in the same folder as your **testacular.conf.js** containing;

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   exec "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" \
   --user-data-dir="/tmp/testacular" \
   --disable-extensions \
   --no-default-browser-check \
   --no-first-run \
   --disable-default-apps \
   --use-fake-device-for-media-stream \
   "$@"
   ```

You may need to `chmod 775 chrome_without_extensions.sh` to give permissions to run the script.

Now when you next run Testacular - any extensions like LastPass shouldn't interrupt you.

Hope this helps someone.